# Beamer semibold font

Tags: beamer, fonts

Since the bold font in beamer is too thick, I am searching for a semi-bold font style. Does anybody know how to load the semi-bold font of "computer modern sans serif", which is the default in beamer class ?

Since a font that looks similar to "computer modern sans serif" is also OK for me, I tried other fonts (like opensans) which have predefined semi-bold font styles, but they look quite different from the default font.

A minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}    
Normal font\\
Searching for a semi-bold style of computer modern sans serif font\\
\textbf{Bold font}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use T1-encoding. At this size it will look less bold. Beside this there is a semi bold condensed variant:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

Normal font\\
Searching for a semi-bold style of computer modern sans serif font\\
\textbf{T1: Bold font} {\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont \textbf{OT1 Bold font}} 

{\fontseries{sbc}\selectfont semibold font}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I face some issues. While compiling in Latex (with T1 encoding), my output letters are feathering (letters look like feathered writing from a fountain pen). The feathering is gone when compiling in XeLatex, but that produces thick bold font (equal to the output without T1 encoding).

Which tex engine are you using ? Do I need to install anything extra (am using texlive and have already installed the extra-fonts) ?

Comment: Install the cm-super fonts (no idea where there are in your system).

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea with tikz overlay (not really recommended):

```
\documentclass[6pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\semibold}[2][0.1]{\tikz[remember picture,inner sep=0]%
\node(A1){\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\color{black!70!white}#2\end{minipage}};%
\foreach \i in{-#1,0,#1}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0,remember picture,overlay]\node[xshift=\i pt,yshift=-\i pt] at(A1){\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}#2\end{minipage}};%
\node[xshift=-\i pt,yshift=\i pt] at(A1){\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}#2\end{minipage}};%
\end{tikzpicture}}%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}    
Normal font\\
Searching for a semi-bold style of computer modern sans serif font\\
\textbf{Bold font}

\semibold{Semi bold text here}

\semibold[0.15]{Semi bold text 2 here}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Uses minipage and so can be used for paragraphs (textwidth could be changed if needed or added as an argument)

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Koleyger. Yours is also an acceptable suggestion.

Comment: welcome @Ashok. have a nice night.