# Make the font thicker in Beamer

Tags: fonts, fontspec

Is it possible to make the font thicker (not larger) in Beamer like the one showed below?

[image]

Below is the fonts one can get with the solution suggested in the post @marmot refers to

[image]

Comment: Are you aware of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396313/beamer-semibold-font)?

Comment: Thanks, @marmot. I was not aware of the post you referred. However, the solution there is not quite nice as I am hoping for. I added the pictures for comparison in my original post.

Comment: What have you tried? Which font is it? If it is in a PDF, you can get the font information. Have you looked in the LaTeX Font Catalogue?

Comment: I do not know which font it is. I saw it from a pdf file and it looks similar to the font I am using amsfont (I guess) accept it is thicker but not as thick as bold.  My Beamer header is as follows: \documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> { \usetheme{boxes} }
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,comment}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}